# Overload resolution with rvalue and lvalue reference candidates when passed empty initializer list

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

int Baz(const Foo&) { return 0; }
int Baz(Bar&&) { return 1; }

int main()
{
  return Baz({});
}
```

Is this call ambiguous? MSVC chooses the rvalue reference overload. GCC says it is ambiguous. Clang also chooses the rvalue reference but no longer if it's `int Baz(std::vector<Bar>&&)` instead or if Bar gets a constructor taking a std::initializer_list.

Is `{}` to `Bar` a standard conversion sequence?

Can someone explain why this does or does not apply:

> 3. A standard conversion sequence S1 is better than a standard
>    conversion sequence S2 if
>
> [...]
>
> c) or, if not that, both S1 and S2 are binding to a reference parameter to something other than the implicit object parameter of a ref-qualified member function, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue while S2 binds an lvalue reference to an rvalue

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)

Comment: `A standard conversion sequence` Yes, but that is when you actually have one type and convert it to another. But what type is `{}`..? See [viable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Viable_functions) section.

Comment: The wording is kinda defective (https://wg21.link/cwg1536), but we all know that a temporary object is created and binding an rvalue reference is better that binding an lvalue one.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned in the question, the standard says in [over.ics.rank]/(3.2):

> Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>
> ...
>
> - `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings (11.6.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a *ref-qualifier*, and `S1` binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and `S2` binds an lvalue reference
>
> ...

So GCC is wrong here.

Actually Clang can be similarly deceived by adding default constructors in the structs:

```
struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo() = default;
};
struct Bar {
    constexpr Bar() = default;
};

constexpr int Baz(const Foo&) { return 0; }
constexpr int Baz(Bar&&) { return 1; }

int main() {
  static_assert( Baz({}) == 1 );
}
```

MSVC is the compiler that correctly selects `Baz(Bar&&)` overload here, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sMcx9ro1x